# Extract Slice - 99 Problems question #18 (Kotlin)

Tags: generics, kotlin

I need to extract a slice from a list:

```
assertThat(slice(3, 7, "abcdefghijk".toList()), equalTo("defg".toList()))
```

I have:

```
@Suppress("unused")
fun <T> slice_(from: Int, to: Int, list: List<T>) = list.subList(from, to)
```

My solution so far is:

```
fun <T> slice(from: Int, to: Int, list: List<T>): List<T> = list.filterIndexed { index, it ->
    (index == from) && (it.size == to-from)
}
```

However IDE sees *size* as an unresolved reference so I tried to add an extension property

```
private val Any?.size: Any
get()= this.length
```

But I get unresolved reference for length. Obviously, I am doing something wrong in terms of introducing size in my function. How could I get around it?

I am very knew to Kotlin so please avoid comments that indicate my lack of knowledge on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using generics and `<T>` can be any object, not having `size` or `length`. Maybe you want to limit `T` to be subclass of something, that has size/length?

Edit:
Or if you are trying to access size of the list, just use `list.size`.

Either way, you probably just want to check, if the current foreach index is within limits, you can do it using [Ranges](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html):

```
fun <T> slice(from: Int, to: Int, list: List<T>): List<T> = list.filterIndexed { index, it ->
    index in from until to
}
```

Comment: The solution with the range worked and it is way less code than playing around with generics.However, since *it* is not used I replaced it with *_* .  I still need time to get familiar with how easy ranges are in kotlin. Thank you.

Comment: No worries! I like that you included test case in your question, that made things faster and easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you :) I try to nagivate myself first to the tests when I deal with pure problem solving questions as you can extract a lot of the logic from a test and then build up your code.